# What is the growth rate of the products of binomial coefficients?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, summation, binomial-coefficients

**Claim:** Experimental data seems to suggest that

$$
{n \choose 1^a b}{n \choose 2^a b}{n \choose 3^a b}\cdots {n \choose m^a b} 
\sim \exp\bigg(\frac{2n^{1 + \frac{1}{a}}}{ab+3b}\bigg)
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are a fixed positive integers and $m$ is the largest positive integer such that $m^a b \le n$.

Note that the above asymptotic are supported by the data even if we relax the condition that $a,b$ are integers and allow them to be reals $a > 0, b > 0$ and replace $k^a b$ with $\lfloor k^a b\rfloor$.

As an illustration, for $a = 3, b = 1$, the $\%$ error between the asymptotic and the actual product is shown below.

**Note**: [Posted in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338167/what-is-the-growth-rate-of-the-products-of-binomial-coefficients) since in it unanswered in MSE

**Update 19-Dec-19**: Combined the two individual claims into a single claim based on experimental data.

[image]

Comment: i would play with Stirling's approximation, may make things easier

Comment: I would also expect the denominator to be something like $a+e$ instead of $a+3$...

Comment: @gt6989b I have a proof using Stirling's approximation  for the simpler case $a = 1$ and the RHS is $e^{n^2}/2$ so the only constant that can fit in the generalization is 3

Comment: Great, happy to be wrong :-)

Comment: Presumably when one takes the logarithm of the left-hand sides and applies Stirling's approximation, the resulting expression is a Riemann sum for some integral....

Comment: $a,b$ are fixed, and $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, asymptotic growth rate for fixed $a,b$ as $n \to \infty$